# доступ к ячейке таблицы через стиль

Tags: jquery

как в строке таблицы:

```
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_lblCard">27077932</span>
                    </td><td style="font-weight:bold;">BERAL</td><td align="center">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_lblQty" style="background-color:Transparent;font-weight:bold;">3</span>
                    </td><td align="center">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_Label3">254,64</span>
                    </td><td align="center" style="font-weight:bold;">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_Label2">313,21</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_lblPastaba">z zestawem montaэowym</span>
                    </td><td valign="middle">
                        <img id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_imgType" title="0" class="AlgMdl" src="/emini/Images/ratingplus.gif" style="border-width:0px;">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_lblStore" title="1800" style="background-color:Transparent;">RZESZУW</span>
                    </td>
        </tr>
```

вытянуть "Beral" c помощью jquery/phpquery?Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот доступ к тексту элемента:

```
var text = $("#dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock_ctl02_lblCard").parent().siblings('td:first').text();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNqErK

Comment: Да,но <td style="font-weight:bold;">BERAL</td> не имеет <span id....>У него есть только font-weight:bold,который повторяется и у других елементов по всей таблице,и значение даной ячейки встечается не один раз,оно есть в каждой строчке таблицы.

Comment: так Вам что нужно выбрать ? только один элемент ?

Comment: нет,нужно из  <td style="font-weight:bold;">BERAL</td> взять значение из всех строк таблицы

Comment: приведите весь html код

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fqc3snx7Qy67uyovfWcSLMW8Ce7dBIYxHso1ZSOQV0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `$('#dnn_ctr372_eMini_Stock_gvStock td:nth-child(4)').each( function (i,e) {
               console.log('№ ' + i + ' ' + $(this).text())
           })`

Выводит в консоль номер строки + текст.

Comment: Пример с сменой цвета http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZpLaP?editors=1010